# counter in TOC fails when using xparse command instead of LaTeX2e command

Tags: macros, sectioning, counters, expansion, xparse

Here I define a custom sectioning command, `\Unit`, which prints a numbered subject heading and adds it to the table of contents. If I use `\newcommand` for the command that creates the numbered label, everything works fine. But if I replace that with the `xparse` version, `\NewDocumentCommand`, the numbers are missing from the TOC labels.

In the MWE below, you can reproduce the error by swapping out the `\newcommand` definition of `\UnitLabel` for the one with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{Unit}

% Numbering disappears in TOC if xparse version is used
% \NewDocumentCommand{\UnitLabel}{}{% 
\newcommand{\UnitLabel}{%
  \makebox[4.5em][l]{Unit \Roman{Unit}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Unit}{ m }{%
  \stepcounter{Unit}
  \def\ThisUnit{\UnitLabel{}#1}
  \section*{\ThisUnit}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\ThisUnit}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Unit{Exordium}

\lipsum[1]

\Unit{Disputatio}

\lipsum[2]

\Unit{Peroratio}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Here is the desired output, using `\newcommand`:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` -- this does not allow an optional argument at the end of the argument list, but this is no issue here!

The `\NewDocumentCommand` version isn't expandable, see e.g. `\show\UnitLabel`:

```
\UnitLabel=\protected macro:
->\makebox [4.5em][l]{Unit \Roman {Unit}}.
l.25 \show\UnitLabel
```

i.e. `\UnitLabel` is protected.

The `xparse` manual clearly states, that the commands `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\RenewDocumentCommand`, `\ProvideDocumentCommand` and `\DeclareDocumentCommand` generate robust commands by design:

> With the concept of an argument specifier defined, it is now possible
>   to describe the methods available for creating both functions and
>   environments using xparse. The interface-building commands are the
>   preferred method for creating documentlevel functions in LATEX3. All
>   of the functions generated in this way are naturally robust (using the
>   e-TEX \protected mechanism).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{Unit}

% Numbering disappears in TOC if xparse version is used
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\UnitLabel}{}{% 
  \makebox[4.5em][l]{Unit \Roman{Unit}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Unit}{ m }{%
  \stepcounter{Unit}
  \def\ThisUnit{\UnitLabel{}#1}
  \section*{\ThisUnit}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\ThisUnit}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Unit{Exordium}

\lipsum[1]

\Unit{Disputatio}

\lipsum[2]

\Unit{Peroratio}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain why? The warning against using `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` in the `xparse` documentation is pretty strong. Is the problem with expansion in the `\def\ThisUnit` line?

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Yes -- `\def\ThisUnit` does not get expanded since `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't expanded (I added some lines in between to the post)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the `xparse` standard commands were protected. I just realized I can simply use `\def\UnitLabel{...}` and it works fine.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: That's 'always' possible ;-) Others will frown about the mix of `\def` and `\NewDocumentCommand` however ... others, not me ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Define `\UnitLabel` with an argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{Unit}

\NewDocumentCommand{\UnitLabel}{m}{% 
  \makebox[4.5em][l]{Unit #1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Unit}{ m }{%
  \refstepcounter{Unit}%
  \section*{\UnitLabel{\Roman{Unit}}#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\UnitLabel{\Roman{Unit}}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\Unit{Exordium}

\lipsum[1]

\Unit{Disputatio}

\lipsum[2]

\Unit{Peroratio}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

This way, the argument will be expanded and the `.toc` file will look like

```
\contentsline {section}{\UnitLabel {I}Exordium}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\UnitLabel {II}Disputatio}{1}
\contentsline {section}{\UnitLabel {III}Peroratio}{1}
```

You have an advantage with this approach, because you can redefine `\UnitLabel` during the typesetting of the table of contents.

Comment: +1, among other things, also for using `\refstepcounter` and not `\stepcounter` (readers, pay attention to this detail…)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: The `\stepcounter` usage isn't really the issue here, in my point of view. In fact, the O.P. and I've try to figure out how to improve the general approach of doing the `\Units` (we've exchanged mails)

Comment: @AndrewCashner `\stepcounter` resets child counters, and `\refstepcounter` does `\stepcounter`. The only difference between them is that `\refstepcounter` also sets the current reference for usage with `\label`.